# Selectively disabling notifications in macOS

Tags: catalina, notifications

At random intervals, DropBox pops up a notification telling me that it's almost full and that I should buy an upgrade. There is no way to disable this notification within the DropBox app (it's how they make money after all), but I would like to block it.

However, I still want to see other notifications from DropBox. So I want to block notifications from this app selectively based on their content, e.g. only if they contain the string "almost full".

So:

- Is there a way to do this from within System Preferences? (It seems not but there's no harm in asking.)
- Is there a way to do it by typing something clever at the terminal?
- Is there a reputable third-party app that can do it?

**PS:** I'm 100% certain there is no feature in DropBox to disable these notifications. The question is about whether there is a way in MacOS or a third party app to filter notifications from a given app selectively based on content. Presumably, if a solution exists, it will not be specific to the DropBox app but will be a general solution to the problem of filtering notifications.

Comment: @nohillside how are these edits helpful? You're just removing content. I'm not expecting an answer to this any time soon, but I would like to please be allowed to include all the relevant content in the question, on the off chance someone does know.

Comment: I'm not removing anything. I'm changing the text "Tt" to "It" in the first bullet point! Fixing a typo only!

Comment: Ah shoot, I keep getting confused and rolling back to revision 1 by mistake. What I actually want to do is roll back just the vandalism, and keep the changes I made to the question

Comment: @IconDaemon sorry, I didn't mean you! Another user keeps making major changes to the content of the question. I also didn't mean to roll back your edit, I'll fix that

Comment: A question which starts with "It's time for another question that will 100% definitely get no votes or replies, but I'll ask it anyway" reads more like a rant than a question and doesn't help to get answers. Also it's hard to understand why on one side you are worried about not getting an answer and on the other hand refuse any attempt to improve the question to increase the chance of actually getting answers. Improving posts by editing is a key aspect of all SE sites (see https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/editing), is has nothing to do with vandalizing.

Comment: @nohillside that initial joke at the start of my question was probably a bad idea - I've no objection to it being removed. (I realise I've kept reinstating it, but that wasn't intentional - I hit 'rollback' without realising it was rolling that back as well.) It's great that you'd like to increase the chances of this getting an answer, but from my end I only care about answers that solve the problem I want to solve, and I prefer not to trade off the quantity of answers against the signal-to-noise ratio. I like to keep things specific because it makes relevant answers more likely.

Comment: Based on all I've learned on AD about writing questions which get answers I doubt your last sentence is true. Do we want questions to be specific? Sure we do. But there is a limit to that, if a question gets too specific people with partial solutions/ideas just skip it and move on. This reduces the value of the question both for you and for others as things you consider to be noise can have value for others with a similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no. Dropbox notifications are all or nothing. Selecting which sort of notification to ignore is not an option - it just isn't granular enough. I've searched for an official Dropbox feature or enhancement request mechanism, and in the Dropbox Community forums there is a Share an Idea section which may be actually viewed by Dropbox developers.
Good Luck

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm aware it can't be done within the DropBox app - the question is whether there's a way within MaxOS itself or a third-party app to filter the notifications based on content. It's kind of a long shot, but you never know.

Comment: Ah, I just realised someone had edited the question to make it ask about something other than what I originally wrote, so this is a very reasonable answer to the question as it was at the time of your answer. I've edited to revert the vandalism.

Comment: There's nothing I can find in the Dropbox > Preferences > Notifications section to enable a change to notifications in the granular way you want. From the looks of things, Dropbox developers follow the macOS Notifications guidelines, which do not allow for modifications on the user end.

Comment: Yes, I very much doubt that DropBox will add a feature that lets you disable this. Subscriptions are their main (only?) source of income, and if you can't disable it you're more likely to pay them to make it go away. But that doesn't rule out either some clever hack or a third-party app that might be able to achieve it.